# assetic:watch error - unserialize(): Error at offset

Tags: symfony, npm, assetic

I was using everyday assetic in work (OS: Win7) but today i was runned command: `php bin/console assetic:watch` and get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 25228 bytes

I was try clear cache - don't help.

I not delete any file and in repository that file not exist and this project is on 3 machines (don't have access now only to 1) and everywhere it works...

Nothing was updated or installed to project so far as i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So helped delete all files with prefix `assetic_watch_*` in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\`

Answer (score 1):

`bin/console assetic:watch --force` also cleared for me.